# bxSlider:bug when carousel too fast

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mobile, bxslider

Description:

scrolling back and forth on through the carousel too fast will sometimes break the carousel and cause the first and last item in the carousel to not have the scroll stop in the correct spot.

my code:

```
var bx1 = $('.featured-products').bxSlider({
      slideWidth: windowsize,
      minSlides: 1,
      maxSlides: 1,
      moveSlides: 1,
      slideMargin: 5,
      autoHover: true,
      pause: 4000,
      speed: 500,
      auto: false,
      touchEnabled: true,
      infiniteLoop: false,
      hideControlOnEnd: true
});
```

question:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lchEj.png)

View the bx-slider document, modify the width of the slidewidth, set specific numbers, and obtain the current size.